# JSON Stringy with Escape Characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I wrote some script to get data from db as json, process it and generate the sql statements and got stuck here. below is the json generated by database when we export as json

```
{
      "id" : 12345,
      "data" : "{\"title\":\"Hello world\"}"
}
```

when i do `JSON.Parse(data)` it converts to object which is good because i can grab the title value, i grab title and do my api call process and update the value of title which is working fine.

when i do `JSON.stringify(data)`, I am not getting the string in below format, so when go back and try to do update in database using this value it throws error because of string formatting, its lot of rows, so i cannot manually change the escape characters

```
"{\"title\":\"Hello world\"}"
```

is there any way i can get back to this format so its easy to update db back, I gave an example here to make it simple, but along with title data has more properties,
any hint or direction is appreciated

Comment: What format are you getting back when you stringify it?

Comment: regular key value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double `JSON.stringify` will do the trick for you

```js
const someImportantThing = JSON.parse("{\"title\":\"Hello world\"}")
someImportantThing.title = someImportantThing.title + " StackOverFlow is here"

const stringified = JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(someImportantThing))
console.log(stringified)
```

Comment: you are genius, that did the trick, you saved my day, Thank you so much